# RecyclerView which display and return different Values

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I am displaying list of check-boxes in horizontal `RecyclerView`.

It display values such as `{"Rd" , "Gr" , "Yl"}` but when user selects any of this value it should return  `{"RED" , "GREEN" , "YELLOW")`

How can I bind these two value that show and return differently?

I am taking display values from `R.string-arry`

I created another string-array of actual values, and when user checked any of `checkboxes` I get that ID and replaced it with actual values.

For e.g. If user has selected "Gr" I get ID=1 then replaced with actual string-array

But this only works when code-color and original-color are in order. In my app I sometimes use Red,green,blue or sometimes green,yellow,blue. So, this won't help me.

Comment: provide `JAVA` code. This question sounds like - please write this code for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood, you need a mapping between GR and Green, RD and Red etc.

You can try using a Hashmap.

```
 HashMap<String,String> colourMap = new HashMap<>();
 colourMap.put("GR","GREEN");
 colourMap.put("RD","RED");
```

And then you can retrieve the respective value for your colour code:

```
String colour = colourMap.get("GR");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `HashMap` which will bind the two `arrays` as key value pair

```
public HashMap<String,String> bindColors() {
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    int length = orginalColors.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        map.put(orginalColors[i], codeColors[i]);            
    }
    return map;
}
```

And for getting the Colors in code.

```
    HashMap<String, String> keyPair = bindColors();
    orginalColorsNewArray = keyPair.keySet().toArray(new String[keyPair.keySet().size()]);
    codeColorsNewArray = keyPair.values().toArray(new String[keyPair.values().size()]);
```

or use `.get()` function

```
   keyPair.get("YELLOW")
```

Now it will be easier for you to access the codes by `id/position`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that, but this only works when code and original color are in order. In my app I sometimes use Red,green,blue or sometimes green,yellow,blue. So, this won't help me.

Comment: Does both Array get shuffled or just one? @ShaishavJogani

Comment: actually there are many (>10) list which displays color codes in random order in one activity. So, it would be better if I can able to just bind Actual values with code instead creating that ,much amount of string-arrays.

Comment: OK i will propose on solution.. Accept if found useful @ShaishavJogani